# Why Github API does not allow password grant type for mobile app?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, github-api

Github API does not allow to use OAuth implicit grant type for Non-Web Application. Basic Authentication is supported. I'm implementing APIs for our own mobile app and third 3rd-party developers. In this case, I guess the password grant type is suitable. I have no idea why Github does not use it. Do you know why?

https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/